# In wxwidgets, how do I lock a vector that is shared between gui thread and worker thread?

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

If I can't call lock on a mutex in the main application thread (my event handler because you can't lock the main gui thread), how do I share any information between my worker and my main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have your worker thread communicate with the main thread through the event handling system.  Use [AddPendingEvent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8.7/wx_wxevthandler.html#wxevthandleraddpendingevent) to send status messages back to the main thread and [ProcessEvent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8.7/wx_wxevthandler.html#wxevthandlerprocessevent) to handle the updates.